# MSAA black edge jaggies similiar to pre-multiplied texture

Tags: opengl, textures, msaa

I am trying to render a smooth AA text.

I've created a polygon mesh using a tessellator, then using a MSAA pass to get smooth edges.

*Weirdly the MSAA pass will result with black jaggies, around the edges (similar to pre-multiplied texture)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DfzW.png

Weirdly because if I do a unpremultiplication the result is fine! ,see second attachment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nzzN.jpg

I am almost 100% positive its the MSAA that causes this issue because If I turn the MSAA off, I get the regular white jaggies (steps)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, 
It seems doing "per pixel geometry" vector art (s.a bezier curves) does not work well with MSAA (not sure why)

May need to change my text algorithm.